# is using li better than DIV possibly for page performance?

Tags: html, performance

Maybe this is a stupid question, but is using li better than using div's possibly for page performance or resources?

Comment: The only performance difference is what goes *inside* the element (e.g bytes - sent over the wire). Choose elements based on logic - not performance considerations. Optimize *after* you have made those decisions.

Comment: `<li>` and `<div>` have very, very different purposes. They aren't even related, why would it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would performance matter more than anything? Use `<li>` only when you want to mark up a list, use `<div>` for sections/blocks of information.

Some browsers tend to render `<li>` as bulleted list items; if you *really* want to talk about performance, chances are it'll be a browser performance hit to strip the list styles from those elements using CSS anyway.

Comment: It kind of depends on what you want your page to look like when styles are disabled or if the network is so messed up your stylesheet doesn't load.

Answer (score 4):

please check this, it might be very useful

[Why should I use 'li' instead of 'div'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div)