# Why do so many jQuery sliders make use of lists instead of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I use ‘li’ instead of ‘div’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div)

I'm figuring out how to make a perfect slideshow/homepage slider. Many tutorials and examples use li elements for each slide, while others use divs. What would be the benefit of using list items? It looks convoluted to me: normally divs are used to separated content fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **div** is used for logical grouping of enclosed elements.
- **li** is used to define list items.

If you need to express a list of items, using 'li' is more semantically appropriate. In this case, you have to represent a list of images in the slider. So it is better to use 'li' instead of 'div'.

Although it's a good practice to use lists for this scenario, there's no technical advantage choosing one over the other.

Further reading:  [Why should I use 'li' instead of 'div'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div)

Answer (score 2):

It will mostly be for semantic reasons - you're storing/accessing a list of content items, it makes sense to store it in a list conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential advantages of using `div`s to `li`s.

1. The `div` instructions in your CSS may already have the `margin` and/or `padding` attributes that you'd like to implement with the inner items of your jQuery plug-in (or slider in this case).
2. Templating can be easier with `div`s because the inner items don't need to be `li`s.

Otherwise, I agree with the other answers.

- `li` is much more consistent with the semantic model.