# Should I be using Div, Span, Nav, or header tags

Tags: css, html, styles

http://websterglasssandiego.com/

https://github.com/GaretWebster/WebsterGlass/issues/1

I have a Navigation Pane that I used to have an H2 tag around, but I decided to change it for a div tag as I didn't want to waste an SEO opportunity on words like Home and About. 
I am currently using 2 Divs around the same element, the NavDiv tag creates the background image and the NavText div contains the Nav text, which is centered by the css. Would it be better to use a span or nav tag?

Also should I be putting these Nav elements in a list? What would the advantages and disadvantages of this be?

Any critiques on my code at all would be appreciated as this is my first site and I am trying to practice better coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 has a tag specific to navigations (`nav`). You can read about it here: http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Inside this `nav` tag, you'd have an unordered list for each of your menu items.

So your HTML would be:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quote</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Ideally, this would be the best way to do your navigation.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using lists for navigation is more semantic than a div with anchor tags. It's also proven to be better for screen readers and other users understand your content. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div/549692#549692)

Answer (score 0):

**`<nav>`**

For your navigation, use the `<nav>` tag, as that is more semantic.

> The HTML Navigation Element (`<nav>`) represents a section of a page
>   that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with
>   navigation links. via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Nav Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Nav Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Nav Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**`<span>`**

> The HTML `<span>` element is a generic **inline** container for phrasing
>   content, which does not inherently represent anything." via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

```
<p>Here is an example of <span>inline-text</span> in a paragraph tag. It can be used in a block-level element without disrupting flow.</p>
```

**`<div>`**

> The HTML  element (or HTML Document Division Element) is the
>   generic container for flow content, which does not inherently
>   represent anything. via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

```
<div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Anything goes in here</p>
</div>
```

You might also want to research **[ARIA roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles)** which allow for enhanced accessibility metadata. via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques)