# Whats the point in using ordered lists if we tweak them until they behave like regular divs?

Tags: html, css

I found my self using unordered lists for breadcrumbs, menu bars, thumbnails, blog article lists, form fields, etc.

I strip the decoration of the `<li>`, change its `display` for horizontal-vertical positioning, insert text, links, spans, imgs, links, paragrahs, titles, form inputs, etc. between the `<li>`, and a bunch of css styles are applied that do not correspond to the spirit of the original concept

I add the semantics in its classes.

And lately I have started to include roles here and there, so I have `role="list"` or `role="menu"`.

Even if I consider, for example, the breadcrumbs as a list (there are a lot of discussion about it), whats the point?, if I am denaturalizing the original behavior of the original HTML tag!

The only moment I see them as a "list" is when css styles are not properly loaded. But as they are not intended to be "real lists", the resulting HTML is somehow wrong, isn't it?

So I am tempted to convert all `<ul><li>` to `<div>`, unless I need a "real list".

What can I find in `<ul><li>` syntax or behavior that prevents me to do that?

**UPDATE:**

The question is almost answered in [Why should I use 'li' instead of 'div'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div) 
but I want to insist, for future readers, in something I have learned reading that answer: **A list is a list. It doesn't matter that the plain html design of a list seems like a grocery list. A list is a list.**

Nevertheles, some abuse can happen, for example using lists to layout a form.

Instead replacing lists by divs, I am going to replace some divs by lists.

Comment: "I add the semantics in its classes." There's your first mistake - classes have zero semantic value. <div class="navigation"> is as semantically meaningful as <div> - which is to say, not at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div

Comment: `<ul>` is an *un*ordered list.

Comment: Also, a list of menu items is still a list. It doesn't go against the "original concept."

Comment: Use a list, if you want a list. Don't think about the styling. If it's content is in fact a list ( of subpages for example ) use a list.

Comment: HTML is about the elements content, not about the look.

Comment: ^ Tweaking a list element until it *looks* (not behaves) like a div doesn't change the fact that it is still a list element at heart.

Comment: already justified here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div

Comment: Not everybody can see that your list is styled (or not) as a `div`. Screen reader users don't know how you display the list, but they know it's a list.

Answer (score 3):

It would be erroneous to think of Hypertext Markup as a framework describing 2-dimensional visual layout. It does not. All HTML does is tell the User-Agent (normally the browser) what role each element plays in the document.

All too often, HTML is (mis-)understood as a 2-dimensional Desktop Publishing tool because all browsers apply default visual styles and visual layout to elements. The layperson then mis-attributes those visual styles, considering them properties inherent to the element.

But they are not.

When first encountering HTML, a lot of people can be forgiven for thinking that `<h1>...</h1>` creates a headline in the Times New Roman font, bold, 16pt and that an `<h2>...</h2>` creates a headline in the Times New Roman font, bold, 14pt.

But it's not the HTML which describes how those elements should display visually... *the browser alone* is responsible for applying those default visual styles.

On it's own, all HTML does is say:

`<h1>...</h1>` is a first-level heading.

`<h2>...</h2>` is a second-level heading.

That's it.

How those first and second level headings then appear visually on a desktop screen, on a smartphone, on a monochrome print-out - or how they sound aurally (in the case of screen-readers) - is entirely down to the medium-specific stylesheet declarations - or, in the absence of a stylesheet, entirely down to the User-Agent's default styles.

In your question, you talk about the *behaviour* of elements.

But, for the vast majority of elements, the *only behaviour* in an HTML element's markup is to describe what role that element plays in the document.

So... if an element in a document is best described as an **Ordered List** - which, as you rightly point out is probably the most appropriate description for any number of page elements including:

1. breadcrumbs
2. menu bars
3. thumbnails
4. blog article lists
5. form fields

then inform the User-Agent by marking up the element as

```
<ol>...</ol>
```